# How can I make a paragraph in HTML not go on a new line?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<span class="icon-top-margin-4 margin-right sprite-book-open"></span>
<p>Topic: No Topic Title</p>
```

and CSS:

```
.icon-top-margin-4 {
    background-color: red;
    content: " ";
    background-image: url(/Images/fugue/sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px; 
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.sprite-book-open{ background-position: 0 -288px;  }
```

What I would like is for the paragraph to start after the icon 
but it starts on a new line. Is there a way that I can make it
start on the same line as the icon? I did try float left on the paragraph but that makes it go before the icon.

Answer (score 2):

p is block element so it comes in new line, you should make it as `inline`.

Add  `.icon-top-margin-4 + p{display:inline;}`

'**+**' selector selects the immediate next element of the mentioned class.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UJATF/7/)**

Comment: Is there some kind of css that I could do that would do display:inline for any P that appears after icon-top-margin-4 ?

Comment: @Anne `.icon-top-margin-4 + p {display: inline;}` would get immediate following sibling. `.icon-top-margin-4 ~ p {display: inline;}` would get all following siblings. If you used the latter you'd need to undo the `inline` style at some point though

Answer (score 1):

You clould also simply nest the `span` inside the `p`.

Comment: This is the simplest options - @Anne, any reason not to amend the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the paragraph style to `display: inline`